# Keep the screen on in Trusted Web Activity

Tags: android, webview, wakelock, trusted-web-activity, powermanager

I want to keep screen on while show trusted tabs.
I was override the WebViewFallbackActivity class and inject this code but it's not working:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "WakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000L);
```

is there any solution to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this!

You need to use the [web WakeLock API](https://developer.chrome.com/en/articles/wake-lock/) instead. I've used it in https://doom-fire.com/, and you can keep the screen on by clicking on the padlock icon. You can check the code my implementation [here](https://github.com/andreban/doom-fire/blob/master/src/wake-lock.mjs).